# Matlab coding help

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I need to graph the following functions on MATLAB:

$$x(t)=\frac{3sin(2t)}{2}\\
y(t)=\frac{-4e^{-1/2t} sin(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}t)}{√15}+2e^{-1t/2}cos⁡(\frac{\sqrt{15t}}{2})\\
h(t)=x(t)+y(t)$$

I have the data points for this functions. I need help making a smooth curve on MATLAB.

I try this code and I get and error:

```
>> x=@(t)(3/2)*sin(2*t);
>> y=@(t)(1/sqrt(15))*exp(-0.5*t)*sin(sqrt(15)*0.5*t)+2*exp(-0.5*t)*cos(sqrt(15)*0.5*t);
>> g=@(t)x(t)+y(t);
>> t=0:0.1:20;
>> plot(t,x(t),y(t),g(t))
```

Comment: you mean plot? did you try the help function ?

Comment: @DramaFreak: something went really wrong with your formatting and you might want to correct.

Comment: Ok, you need to do that. So what have you tried, and how has it failed? Do you own a copy of MATLAB? Does it have any documentation? Have you read it?

Comment: One of the symbols you copied in doesn't render (at least not on my computer) - the one right after the sin/cos's. Could you try again, or simply describe it?

Comment: Your caps lock key is broken. Please replace it.

Comment: Have you considered accepting any of the answers you've received to earlier questions, if any have been helpful? It's fairly simple to do: you can accept one answer per question, and you can do so by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Comment: Please do not yell (ALL CAPS).  Please do format your equations using $\LaTeX$.  You can see how at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  There is some symbol between sin and (2t) that is unreadable on my screen, it recurs later.

Comment: @RossMillikan, (a)gnometorule: They were U+2061 INVISIBLE FUNCTION APPLICATION, and also made the question title unclickable on the main page. DramaFreak were you using some tool to construct the Unicode? Please don't use that.

Comment: Define t after your function definition.

Comment: Also, you need a .* between your exp() and cos() functions.

Comment: I keep getting an error for the second part, especially the y function

Comment: @DramaFreak: You should start accepting answers. Note that it goes with [asking questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nicest ways to handle explicit functions in MATLAB is with anonymous functions. Using the syntax `x = @(t)(...)`, you can replace the ... with function code, and then simply call `x(t)` whenever you want your function evaluated.

So, what you can do for your functions is

```
x = @(t)3/2*sin(2*t);
y = @(t)(-4/sqrt(15)*exp(-1/2*t).*sin(sqrt(15)/2*t)+2*exp(-1/2*t)).*cos(sqrt(15)/2*t);
h = @(t)x(t)+y(t);
```

Note that in the definition of `y`, I used the `.*` operator. This is an element-wise vector multiplication operation, so `[a b].*[c d]` returns `[a*b c*d]`.

Then, you can specify your t-vector in any number of ways, say by using `t = 0:.01:20`, and then you can simply call `plot(t,h(t))`.

---

Why do I like anonymous functions so much?

1. You can specify your functions up-front, without having to specify your domain first.
2. You don't have to worry about row vs. column vectors. Whatever you put in as the argument is what you'll get out.
3. They greatly simplify your code and code structure. Calling `plot(t,h(t))` is unambiguous that $h$ is a function of $t$. By contrast, `plot(t,h)` or `plot(t,x+y)` doesn't give any indication as to the characteristics of the plot. Is it a function? A phase plane? A distribution?

Comment: When I try doing it in your method, I get an error that states "Conversion to double from function_handle is not possible."

Comment: @DramaFreak Post your code in an edit to your post.

Comment: @DramaFreak I'm not sure what issue you're having, but if you are doing it right you should have no issues.

Comment: I get out of work at nine. I will post it then

Comment: @dramafreak the error in your code is because you define t *before* your anonymous functions. Define t after.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I am going to try it now

Comment: Ok it is graphing. The only issue is that the graph is coming as spikes instead of smooth curves

Comment: I am having an another error

Comment: Because your only sampling at 0, 1, 2,... Try t=0:.01:20.

Comment: Yes that is what i have abovem

Comment: @DramaFreak You need to use .* between exp() and cos(). This has been explained three times in this post already. I'm not going to continue to waste my time debugging your code if you're not going to read the two well-written explanations of what you are looking to do... or even trying to understand the fully functional code sample that I provided in my answer.

Comment: i do have the * between them. the issue now is why am i getting sharp lines instead of smooth ones

Comment: Try finer resolution on t. Try 0.01 instead of 0.1. Examine the length of h(t).

Answer (score 2):

Several ways of doing this. Easiest would be to define a vector $t$ from say, $[0,\pi]$ (e.g. `t = linspace(0,pi,100)` for 100 uniformly spaced points between $0$ and $\pi$).

Then create vectors `x` and `y` separately. For e.g. `x = 1.5*sin(2*t)`. Use functions  `sqrt`, `exp`, `sin` and `cos` to create the vector `y`. Don't forget to use `.*` when multiplying two vectors together component-wise (e.g. `exp(-0.5*t).*sin(0.5*sqrt(15)*t)`).

Then, plot it with:

```
plot(t,x+y)
```